# Trace back Python line when using torch.profiler

Tags: pytorch

Here is my torch.profiler output:
[image]

Some of the names I put myself, using `record_function`. However, things like `aten::ne`, I don't know what exact Python lines are calling this operation and taking up the time. Is there a way to reveal which lines are calling `aten::ne`, `SelectBackward` etc?

For `aten::ne`, I found through the docs that this is `torch.not_equals`, but I don't have it in my code anymore. It would be best if I can reveal exactly where the operations in the profiler are being called.